# Linking a framework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating my own iOS framework for use in one of my apps. Now I want to send the app to a friend so that he can run it. I want this to be as simple as possible for him, and I don't want him to have to change of the build settings or link the framework. Given that I don't know what directory he will place the framework in, I think I have 2 options:

**1.**
    When I drag the framework into my app, I don't "copy" the framework, and instead just keep a reference to it. Furthermore, I place my framework in a directory called Project. Then the directory would look like this

```
/Project
    App
    Framework
```

This way, I can send the `Project` file, and when he runs the app the reference to the framework will be the same.

**2.** Copy the framework into the project, and just send the app.

Do both of these methods work the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods should work. Reference to a file is kept in the project, and file is in the project directory. But, for example, if framework file was placed outside the project directory, it wouldn't work.